# Can't set Referer (or Cookie) header in Chrome Extension (Chrome 72+)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In Chrome 72+, setting any header works:

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
        details.requestHeaders.push({name:"Anything", value:"https://google.com"}); 
// ...
```

But setting Referer doesn't:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
    details.requestHeaders.push({name:"Referer", value:"https://google.com"}); 
// ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting on Chrome 72, [according to this post](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/vYIaeezZwfQ), if you're modifying Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, Cookie or Referer, you have to add `extraHeaders` to the `extraInfoSpec` array.
To be backwards compatible (Chrome 71 and below), check for the property `EXTRA_HEADERS`.

```
var extraInfoSpec = ['blocking', 'requestHeaders'];
if (chrome.webRequest.OnBeforeSendHeadersOptions.hasOwnProperty('EXTRA_HEADERS')) extraInfoSpec.push('extraHeaders');

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
// ...
}, {
  urls:[urls]
}, extraInfoSpec);
```

Comment: It's better to link to the official documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I couldn't find any official documentation about this change.

Comment: Oh, they added this change on there and I missed it. Thanks.